# T-SQL query running indefinitely | Not if its batched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hit queit a strange issue here working with a SQL Server table.

With following query, I'm checking if an entry exists that was created between `2023-02-01T04:10:18` and `2023-02-05T04:55:44` (4 days).

This query runs forever:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 1
FROM
    tablexyz t1 (nolock)
WHERE
    t1.col1 = 1
    AND t1.col <= '2023-01-31'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date >= '2023-02-01T04:10:18'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date <= '2023-02-05T04:10:18'
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

While, if I check for a 2 day period, both the queries execute in under 200 ms:

```
-- Executes in 200ms
SELECT
    TOP 1 1
FROM
    tablexyz  t1 (nolock)
WHERE
    t1.col1 = 1
    AND t1.col2 <= '2023-01-31'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date >= '2023-02-01T04:10:18'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date <= '2023-02-03T04:10:18'
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

and

```
-- Executes in 200ms
SELECT
    TOP 1 1
FROM
    tablexyz  t1 (nolock)
WHERE
    t1.col1 = 1
    AND t1.col2 <= '2023-01-31'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date >= '2023-02-03T04:10:18'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date <= '2023-02-05T04:10:18'
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Any idea what could be the reason here? Note that this view(over 3 tables) has over 3 billion rows.

**Indexes on the tables**

```
Non-clustered index col1_col2_IX on (col1, col2)
Non-clustered index kdb_IX on (knowledge_begin_date)
```

**Execution plans:**

- I'm not able to get the actual execution plan of long running query as it is not completing execution. Is there any way to access this ?
- Looking at query plans of batched queries, it is doing an index lookup on `kdb_IX` for all 3 tables the view is over

It seems reasonable to believe that query optimizer should take of this, but strangely that is not the case.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251846/discussion-on-question-by-wira-t-sql-query-running-indefinitely-not-if-its-bat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine the 2 indexes in one query using CROSS APPLY, and see if it helps... something like

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 1
FROM
    tablexyz t1 (nolock)
CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT
    TOP 1 1 x
    FROM tablexyz t2 (nolock)
    WHERE 
        t1.col1 = 1
        AND t1.col <= '2023-01-31'
        AND (t1. ID  = t2.ID)
    ) t2
WHERE
    t1.knowledge_begin_date >= '2023-02-01T04:10:18'
    AND t1.knowledge_begin_date <= '2023-02-05T04:10:18'
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

This is just a strech, depends a lot on the distributions and how will create the execution plan. The idea is that CROSS APPLY should be applied for each row (as a set) and in this case can use the second index.